# How to get the memory usage of a specific process in Linux in the terminal?

Tags: linux, memory, process

This is my first time posting here and I'm a Linux beginner. My question is how do I get the value 204KB in the screenshot using the terminal? Is there a specific command for this?

[image: screenshot]

Many thanks.
Ryan

Comment: Did you tried googling it? https://www.google.com/search?q=How+to+get+the+memory+usage+of+a+specific+process+in+Linux+in+the+terminal%3F

Comment: Try htop or "ps aux | pgrep processname"

Comment: Hi  KamilCuk! Yes, I tried googling it but can't find the answer for my question. I already read those links.

Comment: Hi hashtag-assist, When I tried "ps aux | pgrep processname" it returned the PID not the memory used in Kb or Mb format.

Answer (score 0):

to get the numeric value of memory usage for a process you can use the `pmap` utility